# Searching in Ajax Grid Scaffolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am using Ajax Grid Scaffolder for inline editing of grid in asp.net mvc3. It does not provide searching option by default. Is there any other package which helps the same way as Ajax Grid Scaffolder but with searching option or the only way is to do it manually?